# Referencing a method while setting class attributes

Tags: python, class, static-methods

```
class Something(object):
    our_random = Something.random_thing

    @staticmethod
    def random_thing():
         return 4
```

Of course, this doesn't work, becauese Something doesn't exist when I attempt to call its method. Nor does this:

```
class Something(object):
    our_random = random_thing

    @staticmethod
    def random_thing():
         return 4
```

I've "solved" this by Just placing random_thing()'s definition above the class, but I find this messy.

Comment: Did you mean to call `random_thing`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call it in the `.__init__()` initializer then:

```
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.our_random = Something.random_thing()
```

or call the static method *after* you defined it, but are still defining the class; because it is a static method, you'd have to access it through the `__func__` attribute:

```
class Something(object):
    @staticmethod
    def random_thing():
        return 4

    our_random = random_thing.__func__()
```

If you didn't mean to call it, just create a copy of the method with a different name, just do so after you defined it:

```
class Something(object):
    @staticmethod
    def random_thing():
        return 4

    our_random = random_thing   # our_random as an alias for random_thing
```

The class body is executed as a function, with the local namespace of the function then forming the class attributes. So, like a function, if you want to refer to other objects you need to make sure they are defined first.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Something(object):
    @staticmethod
    def random_thing():
         return 4

    our_random = random_thing
```

Class definitions create a namespace, so you can refer to other names (class attributes) within the class body without needing to access them through the class.